# Get info from two different queries

Tags: sql

This is the query there I am using right now

Here they are:

```
SELECT Filetype AS 'Tipo do ficheiro', 
    ((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS 'Percentagem (%)',
    NULL AS 'Total(KB)'
    FROM infofile 
    GROUP BY Filetype
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,
    ((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)), 
    SUM(Filesize)
    FROM infofile
```

What I want to change here is the possibility to get the result of this query included on the main one

```
    SELECT Filetype, SUM(Filesize) AS 'Total(KB)'
FROM infofile
GROUP BY Filetype
```

This is my output at the moment. What I want to add is the size of each extension. For example .exe - 225

But using that SELECT
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What I am trying to do is just get info from two different columns with that two different queries @Mureinik

Comment: Please share your expected result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `AS 'Total (KB)'` is invalid (standard) SQL

Answer (score 2):

If it is a `SUM` of everything then just put it in a sub query without any joins to the main query.

Also amended your brackets in the `Percentagem`, be careful with BODMAS.

```
SELECT Filetype, 
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS Percentagem,
(SELECT SUM(Filesize) FROM infofile) AS 'Total (KB)'
FROM infofile 
GROUP BY Filetype
```

To have the `SUM` as its own row..

```
SELECT NULL,
NULL, 
SUM(Filesize)
FROM infofile 
UNION ALL
SELECT Filetype, 
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS Percentagem,
NULL AS 'Total (KB)'
FROM infofile 
GROUP BY Filetype
```

The second query would output something like:

```
Filetype Percentagem Total (KB)
NULL     NULL        7894561
1        10%         NULL
2        20%         NULL
3        30%         NULL
4        40%         NULL
```

Comment: That was closer. The problem here is I just want to get one row for the SELECT SUM. You know what I mean?

Comment: Like a total row at the bottom?

Comment: Like a total row and with the same rows as Filetype column

Comment: That total that I want their is different from the Percentagem result. That's why I want it in a different column with just one row

Comment: then use the first query

Comment: Define "simple row"? what do you want too see?

Comment: I just want to see one row with the Total(KB)

Comment: try now with last query

Comment: use ' ' rather than NULL

Comment: It always returns me null

Comment: I tested it in my application and its works in my datagridview. But it is possible to pass that total value to the first row

Comment: I get it. But it doesn't look good in the output of my app. I think I will use use my instead of using NULL values using the values that give the total.

Comment: Could you help me with your query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Filetype, 
      (COUNT(Filetype) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS 'Percentagem', 
      SUM(Filesize)  AS 'Total (KB)' 
FROM  infofile 
GROUP BY Filetype
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one.

```
SELECT A.Filetype, 
    ((COUNT(A.Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS  Percentagem,
     B.filesize AS Totalkb
    FROM infofile A,
    (SELECT SUM(Filesize) filesize FROM infofile) B
    GROUP BY Filetype,Totalkb
```

Comment: "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." - Gave me this message

Comment: That was a great help. But it isn't possible to get the result just in one row without that  values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110905/discussion-between-aritra-bhattacharya-and-rekcs).

Comment: check it now .. @Rekcs

Comment: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." - That was the message

Comment: What do you mean by 'B'?

Comment: I will update in the post the query that I am actually using and then I will explain there what I would like to include.

Comment: can u give some sample data @Rekcs

Comment: the query i have provided will give u the total instead of null for the first 18 rows. execute the new query i have provided and let me know @Rekcs

Comment: 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
Incorrect syntax near ')'.' -  I couldn't get results because gave me this two messages

Comment: This message comes - Column 'B.filesize' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.